# Last item from drop down menu not hovered

Tags: html, css

it may seems to be a dummy question but, second day I'm struggling with that issue. I'm developing responsive website in Joomla, and have the following problem:

When I hover over the active element it's shaking and when I open a drop down list the last item don't have a :hover effect what could that be caused from ? 
Here is the link of the site :

http://mediatecture.dev.diewerkbank.eu/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post some code or make a fiddle. How do you think we can help without code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
.layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-1 > .col1 > ul > li:last-child, .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-2 > .col2 > ul > li:last-child, .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-3 > .col3 > ul > li:last-child, .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-4 > .col4 > ul > li:last-child {
    background: none !important;
}
```

You have a special way of treating the last element of the menu. The above code is in the file `gantry-custom.css` at line 414.

Also, the active effect for it is at the next line, 415:

```
.layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li.active.last > .item {
    background:none; border:none !important; border-radius:0; -webkit-box-shadow:none; box-shadow:none;
}
```

**Edit:** You can simply remove those 2 lines if you don't want any special behavior on the last element of the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you, so much that was the answer. Somehow with the declaration of ".layout-mode-responsive" the both menus are targeted.

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem resolved. Next time when posting on SO though, consider adding some code instead of providing external links.

Comment: I managed the problem with the hover in both of the menus regarding the last child element. But this problem with the jumping menu item on  :hover I just can't follow where is caused from !?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "jumping". The fact that the item appears to move a little on :hover? See line `608` - there is a `padding:0 0;`. Remove it and it won't move anymore.

Comment: I mean when you :hover on the parent items from the main menu, the text is going a bit down, which is not so sensitive, but when I resize the screen in smaller(due to the responsive layout) resolution that affects on the bottom menu border

Answer (score 0):

Like this below css- Remove for background !important. (gantry-custom.css - line no-414)

```
.layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-1 > .col1 > ul > li:last-child, .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-2 > .col2 > ul > li:last-child, .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-3 > .col3 > ul > li:last-child, .layout-mode-responsive .gf-menu li .columns-4 > .col4 > ul > li:last-child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```